# How can I make a domain point to a certain port without doing www.example.com:7000

Tags: dns, port-forwarding, port, domain, forwarding

I have a domain, and I would like to point play.thedomain.com to the ip:port, so I want my play.something.com to point to, let's say 127.0.0.1:25577 (I know, that's localhost, just an example) I do not have access to the network router/switch, I would simply like to do this with my CloudFlare control panel or something along those lines, where I can point sub.domain.tld to the ip with a certain port.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167586). There's something you're trying to do, and you somehow think that making a domain point to a port (which doesn't make any sense) will do whatever it is you're trying to do. It won't, since that doesn't make any sense. If you describe your problem in detail, forgetting how you think you should solve it, we can probably tell you how you can actually solve it.

Comment: You can't assign a domain name to a port.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Sounds like a job for a reverse proxy?

Comment: This needs to be in a FAQ, it's asked so frequently.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this using DNS (by definition of DNS), but you could use a service such as [Afraid Free DNS](https://freedns.afraid.org/) with a Web Forward to achieve the same result. The results are fairly transparent to the end user if you use the `Cloak` option in the Web Forward configuration.